# Docusaurus: how to set a custom url for a doc?

Tags: docusaurus

I have this structure:
-Docs
---folder1
-----docA1
-----docA2
---folder2
-----docB1
Which means by default the URL of docA2 will be "/docs/folder1/docA2", how can I set it to a custom URL, for example "docs/the-doc-2"?

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the top of the file:

```
---
slug: what-ever-url-you want
---
```